# How to implement projection as potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, parity

Consider the quantum mechanics of a single particle in $d$ dimensions, which is governed by the Hamiltonian $$ H = P^2+V(X)\,$$ with $P$ being the momentum operator and $X$ being the position operator, and $V$ is some nice even function.

Let $\mathbb{O}$ be the projection operator onto odd functions (e.g. $\mathbb{O}=\frac{1}{2}(\mathbb{1}-R)$ with $R$ the self-adjoint unitary reflection operator).

My questions:

1. Since $[H,R]=0$, $H$ may be written in block-diagonal form with blocks being eigenspaces of $R$. Then $H\mathbb{O}$ is the odd block only. Is there a way to re-express $H\mathbb{O}$ instead in the form $P^2+\tilde{V}(X)$ with $\tilde{V}=V+f$ and $f$ being some function which would re-create the effect of admitting only odd functions? It is suggestive to consider Dirichlet boundary conditions, and odd functions would certainly obey them. For a Hamiltonian with Dirichlet boundary conditions, we could instead realize it as a Hamiltonian with free boundary conditions and an infinite barrier on the boundary. Is there a similar barrier-type idea for projection onto odd functions (which obey Dirichlet but are still more special).
2. The path-integral gives us a prescription for writing the expectation value $$ \left<\delta_x, \exp(-\mathrm{i}t H)\delta_x\right> = \mathcal{N}\int_{\eta(0)=x,\eta(t)=x}\exp(\mathrm{i}\int_0^t\|\dot{\eta(t')}\|^2+V(\eta(t'))\mathrm{d}t')\mathrm{d}\eta\,. $$ Is there a similar formula for $\left<\delta_x, \exp(-\mathrm{i}t H)\mathbb{O}\delta_x\right>$? I realize this can simply be written as the difference of two propagators, but I am looking instead for an interpretation in terms of paths within the path integral. For example, integrating only over paths which are odd?? or which never reach the origin?? The formulas I know for $\left<\delta_x, \exp(-\mathrm{i}t H)A\delta_x\right>$ assume that $A$ is diagonal in the position basis or in the momentum basis.